# List content not returning in Search Results

Tags: 2013, search, search-results, custom-list

I have a List with an Enhanced Rich Text column `body text` (Multiple lines of text). No results are returning in this list or column.

In List Settings I set `Allow items from this list to appear in search results` to `Yes`. I have Re-indexed the list and ran a Full Site Crawl.

I know Search is setup correctly because it is returning results in other Lists.  Is there something else I need to set on my List or Column?

Comment: How many items in the list? Are items published? Is it a list or a doc lib? Do you errors concerning this list in the crawl logs?

Comment: @Evariste 50 Items in the List. Being used for copy on the site. How do i access crawl logs?

Comment: From the CA, go to Application Services, Search service, Crawl logs.

Comment: No errors in the crawl logs.

Comment: No error... good... but better: do you see the list items, in the logs, as "success"? :)

Comment: It's now working.  I do not know why. #sharepoint